# How do I find the top n values in a collection?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

So I have a column of data that I've separated into a couple of (non-contiguous) collections, and I'd like to highlight the top whatever values in each collection. So far I've managed to highlight every value in each collection, but I have no idea how to find even just the max of a collection, never mind a variable number of top values.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Sub Test()

Dim i As Integer
Dim t As Variant
Dim T1 As New Collection
Dim T2 As New Collection
Dim T3 As New Collection


    'Sort into collections
    For i = 2 To 195
        If Cells(i, 14) = "" Then
                Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ElseIf Cells(i, 14) < 10000 Then
                T1.Add Cells(i, 16)
        ElseIf Cells(i, 14) > 100000 Then
                T3.Add Cells(i, 16)
        Else
                T2.Add Cells(i, 16)
        End If
    Next i

    'colour cells
    For Each t In T1
            t.Interior.Color = RGB(204, 236, 255)
    Next t

     For Each t In T2
            t.Interior.Color = RGB(204, 204, 255)
    Next t

     For Each t In T3
            t.Interior.Color = RGB(204, 153, 255)
    Next t

End Sub
```

I'd like to replace the 'colour cells part with something like

```
For Each t in T1 
    If t > (nth largest value in T1) Then 
        t.Interior.Color = RGB(whatever)
    End If 
Next t
```

I wondered if calling the LARGE function and using a variable for k may work, but I'm afraid the non-contiguous nature of the cells it needs to search wouldn't work in that function.

I'd really appreciate any help in figuring this out <3

Comment: Have you considered conditional formatting? that will show the top 10... but you have to then scroll through to find them... If not large() and then index with match can build you a list...

Comment: I started with conditional formatting but I don’t know how to split it up into three tiers the way the collections do. Index/Match would add a new column and I just want to light up the existing one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use `SortedList` object, instead of `Collection`, and have column P values as its keys and column P cells as its items so that they get automatically sorted by Keys:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim i As Long

    Dim T1 As Object
    Dim T2 As Object
    Dim T3 As Object

    Set T1 = CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList") ' set a sorted list object
    Set T2 = CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList") ' set a sorted list object
    Set T3 = CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList") ' set a sorted list object

    For i = 2 To 195
        If Cells(i, 14) = "" Then
                Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ElseIf Cells(i, 14) < 10000 Then
                T1.Add Cells(i, 16).Value, Cells(i, 16) ' add an element to T1 sorted list with current column P value as key and current column P cell as item
        ElseIf Cells(i, 14) > 100000 Then
                T3.Add Cells(i, 16).Value, Cells(i, 16) ' add an element to T1 sorted list with current column P value as key and current column P cell as item
        Else
                T2.Add Cells(i, 16).Value, Cells(i, 16) ' add an element to T1 sorted list with current column P value as key and current column P cell as item
        End If
    Next i

    ColourIt T1, 4, RGB(204, 236, 255)
    ColourIt T2, 4, RGB(204, 204, 255)
    ColourIt T3, 4, RGB(204, 153, 255)
End Sub


Sub ColourIt(T As Object, ByVal maxElementsNumber As Long, color As Long)
    Dim j As Long, lastElementIndex As Long

    With T ' reference passed object
        If maxElementsNumber <= .Count Then lastElementIndex = .Count - maxElementsNumber 'set last element index to be colored according to sorted list actual items number

        For j = .Count - 1 To lastElementIndex Step -1 ' loop through sorted list items backwards to start from the highest key down to the lowest
            .GetByIndex(j).Interior.color = color ' color current sorted list item
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your help! I used this and it worked but I have no idea what you did so when I tried to modify it I ran into problems. I changed the 4 to a variable and it worked, but then I added a few more sorted lists and it no longer highlights the right number of results. Like it's using the variable as a max. Also I tried to change the thresholds (< 1000 etc) to variables, but I have a couple with two criteria (< a, > b) and it gives me a runtime error failed to compare two elements in the array. So sorry to ask but can you please help me again? idk where to post the code tho

Comment: You are welcome. As per this site rules, if my answer solved the question you posted, then you should accept it. And if in your further development you meet new issues, you should post a new question along with the new code